# google protobuffer how to define list of lists in proto file?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a class with a list of lists field as below:

```
public class MyClass{
   private List<List<String>>
}
```

how to define it in a proto file?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1. You can declare your own "types" in proto files called *message*.
2. If you'd like to declare a list you should use *repeated* keyword.

Combining those two gives us:

```
message ListOfListsOfStrings {
    repeated ListOfStrings listOfStrings=1;
}

message ListOfStrings {
    repeated string strings=1;
}
```

You can then use *ListOfListsOfStrings* message in your proto were appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

I was wondering the same thing and I learned that I can:

1. define as a `stream`
2. define as a `repeated`

as shown in below:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

message Dummy {
  string foo = 1;
  string bar = 2;
}

message DummyList {
  repeated Dummy dummy = 1;
}

service DummyService {
  rpc getDummyListWithStream(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (stream Dummy) {}
  rpc getDummyListWithRepeated(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (DummyList) {}
}
```

so, which one?

> In general, if your use case would allow the client to process the
>   incoming messages one at a time, the stream is the better choice. If
>   your client will just be blocking until all of the messages arrive and
>   then processing them in aggregate, the repeated field may be
>   appropriate, but even in this scenario the stream would work just as
>   well, except for losing some potential compressibility.

referenceed from here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/F23vXwilTq0

Answer (score 1):

Protocol buffer does not have any type of list. But the list is repeated values of string. So we can create one message which has string input and call that message with repeated keyword from another message

For example

```
message person{
   repeated nameList list = 1;
 }

 message nameList{
    string name = 1;
 }
```